# CSS - Connecting multiple :hover with different section

Tags: html, css, hover

I need little help with `:hover` on multiple objects with different colors.
When I hover on the first section, the second one should change the color too.

**HTML**

```
<section class="object1"></section><section class="object2"></section>
```

**CSS**

```
.object1 {
background-color:#F00;
width:100px;
height:50px;
}


.object2 {
background-color:#00F;
width:100px;
height:50px;
}

.object1:hover{
    background-color:#FF0;
    }

.object2:hover {
    background-color:#000;

}
```

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Yep, i forgot to mention it, i already editet post :D (sry )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS's [Adjacent Sibling Combinator `+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) selector to apply changes to `.object2` when hovering over `.object1`, but you cannot do this in reverse:

```css
.object1:hover,
.object1:hover + .object2 {
    background-color:#FF0;
}
```

---

#### Demo

```css
.object1 {
  background-color:#F00;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
}


.object2 {
  background-color:#00F;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
}

.object1:hover,
.object1:hover + .object2 {
    background-color:#FF0;
}

.object2:hover {
    background-color:#000;

}
```

```html
<section class="object1">Section 1</section>
<section class="object2">Section 2</section>
```

Comment: If the elements are laid out strategically, then `~` might work.

Comment: @abhitalks based on the question there would be no need to use `~`.

Comment: Man you are awesome, but it is possible with 3 objects ?
With same method ?

Comment: @user2382619 are you wanting to hover over both `.object2` and `.object3` when hovering over `.object1`? If so you can use `section:hover ~ section`.